# Pandas gives me an empty data frame after filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Head of data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwBg2.png)

[Data dtypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1ZSj.png)

[Empty data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNjkf.png)

Hello,
when I use this code to filter df[df["LONGITUDE"]==29.218140].head(5) , I take an empty data frame. It's float and I dont understand why I'm getting such a frame. I've tried iloc,loc,isin and some other things but nothing's changed. Do you have any idea?? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: is it possible that longitude actually have more than 5 decimal places?

Comment: Welcome, try using inequalities instead of '==' as in `df[df["LONGITUDE"].gt(29.2) & df["LONGITUDE"].lt(29.3)]`

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I created a dataframe with one row with a value that has more decimal places than are displayed.
When I filter by the value that is displayed (in the second cell), since I am not including all the decimal places that are actually stored, it is not being found.

[image]

One solution for your case could be to filter as follows:

```py
df[np.isclose(df['LONGITUDE'], 29.218140)]
```